# How to update the character table of MAX7456

Tags: atmega328

I've got a [MAX7456 chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/MAX7456.pdf) and I am using [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cp4am1f271odcm/max7456.tar?dl=1) library with it. 
But the issue is that the character table is not the one the library needs to function like it should. The "Hello world" example is nowhere near to what it should display, because the character table is wrong.

All the instructions that talk about character set updating require a USB FTDI cable (I don't have one), I am able to  program the board with [USBASP](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/) programmer but that's it. I also have a few Nanos, if that helps.

How could I update the character table to what the library needs (without a FTDI cable) or how to make the sketch included to update the character set work properly?

Comment: In what way is it wrong? Garbage? Inverted? Rotated 90 degress? Please specify.

Comment: ASCII lookup does not work properly.

Comment: Question: `In what way is it wrong?` Answer: `ASCII lookup does not work properly`. Nope, still uncertain what the problem is.

Comment: "The issue is that the character table is not the one the library needs to function like it should." "ASCII lookup does not work properly." The library is not using the right characters, I have no idea how to make this even clearer.

Comment: Give an example: What do you do, what do you expect, what happens, what is the difference between expectation and observation?

Comment: I use the "Hello world" example, load it to the board. It displays stuff on the screen. The characters are wrong because the character table is wrong. It looks up the characters wrong. 

Are my comments using wrong encoding and you are not seeing it right, because I have said the same thing now four times.

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet yet? Specifically pages 34 and 33?

Comment: I posted the datasheet, yes, I have looked at it for some things but my question is how to update the character set to what the library needs, and as I described I do not have a FTDI cable and I don't know how what character set the library needs exactly.

Comment: @Avamander Included in the library is `Max456WriteTable.cpp`. Have a look at that: it appears to be a method of writing characters to the EEPROM on the IC. **HOWEVER** you still haven't said *what is actually displayed on the screen* when you run the "Hello World" example. Please state, unequivocally and explicitly, what you get instead. Better yet, tell it to print out ALL the characters and show us what you get vs. what you've asked for.

Comment: Oh, I must've missed the table write sketch, it does not appear in the examples. I tried to compile the sketch but it fails (IDE 1.6.4).

Comment: @CharlieHanson The character table is wrong; not the one library needs; ASCII lookup does not work; it is not using the right characters. l = @ for ex.

Comment: @Avamander, yes you keep saying that. What characters DOES it use? WHAT DOES IT PRINT INSTEAD OF "HELLO WORLD" ?? This is like getting blood from a stone.

Comment: It says "HE@@O WO(arrow pointing up)@: P- #U(arrow pointing up twice)E+(->)" no sentence comes out right.

Comment: Also, you found the charset updating sketch, how would one make it compile?

Comment: Copy the contents to a new *.ino file, and put the *.h file in the same folder as your *.ino file (unless the IDE finds it by itself).

Comment: "Max7456WriteTable.h:11:21: fatal error: max7456.h: No such file or directory #include <max7456.h>" happens.

Comment: ...copy the h-file into the directory where you have saved the new sketch.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wIExx2t.png happens when all includes work properly. The library is also not working with IDE 1.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem one would need to get the builtin character updating sketch work (Max456WriteTable.cpp in examples folder). After the sketch has been compiled one would have to connect either FTDI cable or a USBASP programmer to the board and upload the sketch to it.

The character set (array) itself used in the code can be updated with the appropriate program available at [this site](http://theboredengineers.com/2012/12/a-max7456-library-for-arduino/).

UPDATE: In the end I solved it [this way](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14739/character-updating-sketch-not-working).

Many thanks to Charlie Hanson & Nick Gammon.